# RestKit parsing nested dictionary

Tags: objective-c, json, restkit

I get this json response calling a REST api:

```
{
"ProfileResponse": {
    "Request_timestamp": 1378473780145780000,
    "Execution_time": 30135057
},
"Results": {
    "newsession": {
        "Sessionid": "110873298014",
        "Status": "ACTIVE",
        "Tag": "GO",
        "TimeStamp": 1378473780146026000
    }
},
"ResultsCount": 0,
"ResultsURL": ""
}
```

and I want to parse this response and get the `newsession` into a session object that have defined as an objective-c class.

I have defined a `base_mapping` that maps the base fields ('PrifileResponse', 'Results', 'ResultsCount', 'ResultsURL'), and another mapping for the 'newsession' and a relationship mapping:

```
RKObjectMapping *baseResponseMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[CSBaseResponse class]];
RKObjectMapping *sessionMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[CSSessionResponse class]];
[sessionMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
     @"Sessionid":   @"sessionid",
     @"Status": @"status"
 }
];

RKRelationshipMapping *relationshipMapping = [RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"Results" toKeyPath:@"results" withMapping:sessionMapping];
[baseResponseMapping addPropertyMapping:relationshipMapping];
```

but I can't access the "newsession",

my question specifically is, is there a syntax that I can use in the "from key path" like `Results.newsession` or something like that to access the inside of "newsession",

or what is the best practice to parse/map this nested structure?

Comment: What is `baseResponseMapping` for, what mappings does it have (just the relation?) and what response descriptor is it connected to?

Comment: Yes, you can use `Results.newsession` to navigate through the JSON.